# Run stored procedure into different compability level than database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an stored that for some reason only runs with SQL Server 2008 compability level in 19 seconds, if I changed it to Compability level to 2017 it takes like 10 minutes to execute, there is any way to execute select statement in stored procedure with compability of 2008? instead change all database compability?

Comment: Have you looked at the estimated query plan in each mode. Your query may need modifying for the newer compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the recommendations I have seen on line when updating to SQL 2107 it that you set the compatibility level to your old server and turn on querystore. Run this for some amount of time to allow the system to capture query plans. Change compatibility level to 2017 and when you find slow running code either fix the query or force the plan to use the one that works better. Or you could set the system to do it for you by turning on autotuning.

You can find information about these at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I search for you recommendation and look into autotunning  in https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/06/11/sql-server-automatic-tuning-around-the-world/ and it works! I really appreciate it . Thanks